# How to retrieve all the data from 3 different tables in one query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to do the following but I don't understand how I will do it:

For every class show me all the students in this class and for every student in this class show me all the statistics of the student.

my models are:

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    day_and_time= models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("classesapp:class_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})


class Students(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    student_class =  models.ForeignKey(
        Classes, related_name = 'students', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("classesapp:student_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

class Statistics(models.Model):
    student= models.ForeignKey(
        Students, related_name='statistics', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
    )
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    dictation_score = models.FloatField()
    writing_score = models.FloatField()
    test_score = models.FloatField()
    grammar_score = models.FloatField()
    in_class_performance = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("classesapp:classes_list")
```

My ClassesDetailView is:

```
class ClassesDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset  = models.Classes.objects.select_related('statistics')
    context_object_name = "class_detail"
    model = models.Classes
    template_name = "classesapp/class_detail.html"
```

I know that I have to overwrite the queryset and I tried select_relatad but still can't find a solution.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It will run through 2 loops. as according to your models `class` can have many `students` and `student` can have many `statistics`.
***updated :***

```
result = []  

for student in Students.objects.all(): 

    student_data = {}
    student_data['student_name'] = student.name
    student_data['class_name'] = student.student_class.name
    statistics_data = []  

    for statistics in student.statistics.all():  

        statistics_data.append({
        'dictation_score': statistics.dictation_score,
        'writing_score': statistics.writing_score,
        'grammer_score': statistics.grammer_score,
        'in_class_performance': statistics.in_class_performance
        })  

    student_data['statistics_data'] = statistics_data  

result.append(student_data)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I tried it in the shell but it doesn't work. The error I get is in `select_related('statistics)` `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'statistics'. Choices are: student_class`. I tried to fix it but still doesn't work. However, this answer you provide if will work how I will do it in ClassDetailView ? I think it will raise a 404 error that classes detail not found because when I tried different queries before asking here always had this error. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @ptifti remove selected_related

Comment: @ptifti i updated my answer . if it is right  please accept the answer and upvote too

Comment: You can optmize the SQL side of things using [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: @NaveenJain Thank you again for your answer. The code you provided is working but it's not what I want and it seems to be like the default queryset for students if I create a StudentsDetailView using ```for student in students: blablabla for stat in students.statistics.all(). Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: @ptifti  `For every class show me all the students in this class and for every student in this class show me all the statistics of the student.`  ?? my answer is for that ok

Comment: @NaveenJain Yes this is what I want to do but I think that your code does  ```for every student show all students information between them is student class name and for every student show me all student statistics``` I think I have to do a third loop at the beginning like for ```For every class in classes show all the students in this class and for every student in this class show all student statistics``` I am really sorry if my question isn't clear enough of I didn't understand your code. I really appreciate your time to help me!

Comment: @ptifti according to your models class can have many student, but one student can attend only one class.  ?? so i am creating an list of students ,they have class name as well because one student only one class .  so there is no use of third loop my friend